# circular linked list and insert at end function in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a circular linked list in C.
But I haven't understood quite well the linked lists.
Well the program gets an int to a function called list_end_ptr which initialises the circular linked list and creates nodes for the int.
Then another function (insert_at_end) puts new nodes on at the end of the initialized list and returns the last node.
A 3rd function prints the linked list (print_list) by getting the end node and printing first the first entered name and finishes with the last.

The idea is to have only an end node and work only with this, but I can't make it work. I have managed to make it partially work, when I print the data are printed in reverse order of the name entry (from last entered to the first).

Any idea?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <strings.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define NUM_PER_LINE 3

typedef struct node
{
    char name[SIZE];   /* SIZE-1 χαρακτήρες και το '\0' */
    struct node * next;
} CListNode;

void get_name(char *a);
void print_list(CListNode *end_ptr);
CListNode *initiate(int n);
CListNode *insert_at_end(CListNode *end_ptr, char *a);

int main(void) {
    CListNode *list_end_ptr;

    int n=6;
    list_end_ptr=initiate(n);
    print_list(list_end_ptr);

    return 0;
}

void get_name(char *a)
{
    char format[10];

    sprintf(format, "%%%ds", SIZE-1);
    scanf(format, a);
}

CListNode *insert_at_end(CListNode *end_ptr, char *a)
{
    CListNode *temp, *head=NULL;

    head=end_ptr->next;
    temp=(CListNode *) malloc(sizeof(CListNode));
    end_ptr->next=temp;
    strcpy(temp->name, a);
    temp->next=head;

    return temp;

}

CListNode *initiate(int n) {

    CListNode *end, *first=NULL;
    int i;
    char new_name;
    end=(CListNode *) malloc(sizeof(CListNode));
    if (end==0) {
        printf("Allocation error...\n");
        exit(0); }
    end->next=end;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (i<1) {
            printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
            get_name(&new_name);
            strcpy(end->name, &new_name);
            first=end;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
            get_name(&new_name);
            insert_at_end(end, &new_name);
        }
    }

    return end;
}

void print_list(CListNode *end_ptr)
{
    int i=1;
    CListNode *str_ptr;
    if (end_ptr == NULL)
        printf("\n List is empty");
    else
    {
        str_ptr = end_ptr->next;
        while (str_ptr !=  end_ptr)
        {
            printf("%s \t", str_ptr->name);
            str_ptr = str_ptr->next;
            if (i%NUM_PER_LINE==0) {
                printf("\n");
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", str_ptr->name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend you are not updating the end pointer for condition i>0.The very first node you create is very much right but when you code starts executing the else part of for loop, the end pointer is not manipulated correctly. Here is the corrected version of the code you have given

For the else part of for loop of the initiate function

```
else
    {
      printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
      get_name(&new_name);
      ptr=insert_at_end(first,end, &new_name);/*insert_at_end returns temp*/
      end=ptr;
    }
```

The insert at end function returns temp so that end pointer can be updated.

For the insert_at_end function just replace the line

```
 head=end_ptr->next;
```

with

```
head=first;
```

Of course, you would have to pass the first pointer in call of the function as well.

So in short,you had almost done the job right and with minute modifications like:

insert_at_end function returned value should be put into a pointer which in turn is used to update end.

We end up with correct code.

Do not forget to update the prototype of function insert_at_end.It should be

```
CListNode *insert_at_end(CListNode *first,CListNode *end_ptr, char *a);
```

Comment: Wierd though,it works for names that are 5 characters or less.

Comment: The issue is that this is a code from an exercise and the insert_at_end cannot change :(

Comment: All code that I had was correct, only think that was missing was a pointer to take the end node that was returning from insert_at_end. I put ptr=insert_at_end and now it's working.

Comment: If the name is longer than 5 characters,the program terminates in one node only.Did you notice?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, inserting at the end of a singly-linked list (which is what you have) is a matter of iterating through the `next` pointer until you get to a `NULL` value, and then create a node, and adjust the previous last node's `next` pointer to point to the new node.

The code includes `<strings.h>` but that should be `<string.h>`.

Also, where your current code has `strcpy` you should probably instead use `strdup` or `strncpy` to make sure you don't overrun your allocated `SIZE` for `name`.

There are a number of problems with this code, but this should get you started:

```
CListNode *initiate(int n) {
    CListNode *end, *first;
    int i;
    char new_name[SIZE];
    end = first = malloc(sizeof(*first));
    if (first == NULL) {
        printf("Allocation error...\n");
        exit(0); 
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the name of the %d person: ", i+1);
        get_name(new_name);
        insert_at_end(end, new_name);
    }

    return end;
}
```

Comment: This still gives the same result as the initial one.

Comment: @ToroLoco: Yes, there are a number of other problems you'll need to address as well.

Comment: the fact is that I the print function works on another implementation that I did with a circular list and gave me the right order. But now it returns a reverse order, so it must be the insert_at_end function that inserts the nodes at the beginning and not at the end. But I can't figure out why and if this is happening.